# А он(,) густой(,) как молоко(,) парил над всем

Tags: пунктуация

"Поле уходило вдаль, растворяясь в тумане, а он, густой как молоко, парил над всем, тянулся, переходя в мутно-серое небо". Владимир Сорокин "Норма".

Я несколько раз встречал подобное обособление в текстах, хотя предложения с такой формулировкой сравнительных оборотов встречаются достаточно редко. Если изъять из предложения данный кусок именно с такой расстановкой, смысл не меняется. Если изымать отдельно "как молоко", выходит, на мой взгляд, несуразно. Тем не менее, встречается и последний вариант пунктуации. Как вернее?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: ***Поле уходило вдаль, растворяясь в тумане, а Он, густой как молокО, парил над всем, тянулся, переходя в мутно-серое небо.***

С точки зрения интонации, совершенно ясно, что оборот «густой как молоко» обособляется как единое целое, иначе предложение не прочитаешь: ударение падает на слово «молоко», но не падает на  слово «густой».

Что касается **конкретного правила** на эту тему, то его довольно сложно найти. К примеру, можно сослаться на  примечание в п.3 Розенталя, где говорится о том, что иногда нужно обозначить, **к какому слову относится сравнительный оборот**.

«Сравнительный оборот с союзом как, находящийся в середине предложения, отделяется запятой, если нужно показать, к какой части предложения он относится:  Я мчался на лихом коне, **как ветер волен и один** — ‘волен и один, как ветер’, а не ‘мчался, как ветер».

https://old-rozental.online/punctuatio.php?sid=147#pp147

В нашем случае  нельзя  делить не части  сочетание «густой как молоко».